# find indeces of rows containing NaN

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

in a pandas dataframe

```
matrix
```

I would like to find the rows (indices) contaning NaN.

for finding NaN in columns I would do

```
  idx_nan = matrix.columns[np.isnan(matrix).any(axis=1)]
```

but it doesn't work with `matrix.rows`

What is the equivalent for finding items in rows?

Answer (score 5):

I think you need [`DataFrame.isnull`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isnull.html) with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) and  [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[df.isnull().any(1)].index)
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],
                   'B':[4,5,6],
                   'C':[np.nan,8,9],
                   'D':[1,3,5],
                   'E':[5,3,6],
                   'F':[7,4,3]})

print (df)
   A  B    C  D  E  F
0  1  4  NaN  1  5  7
1  2  5  8.0  3  3  4
2  3  6  9.0  5  6  3

print (df[df.isnull().any(1)].index)
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

Another solutions:

```
idx_nan = df[np.isnan(df).any(axis=1)].index
print (idx_nan)   
Int64Index([0], dtype='int64')
```

---

```
idx_nan = df.index[np.isnan(df).any(axis=1)]
print (idx_nan)
```

Comment: df.isnan doesn't exist

Comment: sorry np.isnan(matrix)

Comment: Yes, you can aslo use `np.isnan` what is equivalent to `DataFrame.isnull` I think.